# Paginación de resultados con JSP y MySql

Tags: java, mysql, web, jsp

quisiera preguntar si alguien tiene algún ejemplo de paginación en jsp, ya que estoy realizando una página web que contiene una sección tipo blog, donde se realiza una consulta a BD y retorna un arreglo de objetos, quisiera preguntar como puedo paginarlos, para no cargar por ejemplo 100 resultados en una sola página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolví la paginación, utilizando MySql y JSP realice el siguiente código para paginar.

```
<%    
    int pag = 1;
    //Al momento de dar siguiente o presionar otro botón, manda como parametro "pg" con el número de página.
    if (request.getParameter("pg") != null) {
        pag = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("pg"));
    } 
    NovedadServices novedad = new NovedadServices();
    ArrayList<Novedad> n = new ArrayList();
    //Obtengo los datos de la base de datos mediante el crud.
    n = novedad.read();
    //maxPag es la variable para Máximo de Páginas, se haya calculando el tamaño del arreglo de objetos entre el número de
    //Elementos por página.
    int maxPag = n.size() / 9;
    //Aquí hago una operación para obtener el número de registro del que inicia.    
    int regMin = (pag - 1) * 9;
    //Aquí hago una operación para obtener el número de registros máximos para mostrar en esa página.
    //Esto con el fin, de recorrer el arreglo desde el registro mínimo hasta el registro máximo.
    int regMax = pag * 9;
%>

<% //Pregunto si hay más de una página, para comenzar paginación.
                    if (maxPag >= 1) {
                        //Si la página diferente a uno, si agrega el botón anterior.
                        if(pag!=1){%>
                            <li><a href="blog.jsp?pg=<%=pag - 1%>">&lt;</a></li>
                        <%}%>
                        <%//Realizo el for para calcular el máximo de páginas.
                            for (int i = 0; i < maxPag; i++) {
                            //Si la página es igual a la página actual, muestra la etiqueta active.
                                if(i+1==pag){
                        %>
                            <li class="active"><span><%=i+1%></span></li>
                        <%  }//Si no, sigue mostrando las etiquetas normales con la opción para desplazarse.
                            else{%>
                                <li><a href="blog.jsp?pg=<%=i+1%>"><%=i+1%></a></li>
                        <%}}
                        //Sí pagina es diferente al número máximo de páginas, muestra la opción siguiente.
                        if(pag!=maxPag){%>
                            <li><a href="blog.jsp?pg=<%=pag + 1%>">&gt;</a></li>
                <%}}//Si el máximo de páginas no es mayor a 1, muestra solo una página 
                    else {%>
                        <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
                <%}
                %>
```